# If dentro de if MySQL

Tags: mysql

estoy realizando una consulta en mysql y hasta el momento tengo esto

```
SUM(IF(val1 IS NULL, val2, val1 )) AS total
```

Pero es posible poder hacer algo así ?

```
SUM(IF(val1 IS NULL, if(val2 is null, 0, val2) val1 )) AS total
```

Donde yo diga que si `val1` es nulo ponga `val2` pero antes de poner `val2` pregunte nuevamente si esta nulo para poner 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero cambiar a COALESCE

La idea es regresar el primer valor **no nulo**

Quedando

```
SUM(COALESCE(val1,val2,0)) AS total
```

Para este caso `val1 = null, val2 = 5`, regresara 5 porque es el primero que no es nulo de izquierda a derecha

Para el caso `val1 = null, val2 = null` regresara 0 porque 0 es el primer valor no nulo

Para el caso `val1 = 10, val2 = 5` regresara 10 porque 10 es el primer valor no nulo

---

Basado en el comentario

Podemos agregarle un `case`

```
SUM(COALESCE(case when val1 = 0 then null else val1 end,val2,0)) AS total
```

Comment: El problema es que el val1 no siempre será nulo, en ocasiones puede ser 0 y es ahi cuando necesito que coja el valor de val2

Comment: @SantiagoMuñoz Hice una edición, la idea es agregar un case y si val1 es 0 lo pasamos a null, asi seguira funcionando el COALESCE y tomara el valor de val2 en este caso

Comment: Si, lo acab de ver y funciona pefecto ! ty